# DatePicker and ListPicker display incorrectly

Tags: datepicker, nativescript

I am using a DatePicker along with a ListPicker in my Nativescript application. However neither of these elements display correctly. I've had to blank out some sensitive information from the screenshot, but the issue is visible in the DatePicker.

[image: issue]

It seems that the values are offset, and I cannot find out what is causing this. Has anyone else come across this issue before? Or have a fix for it?

These elements are of utmost importance to my project.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the component is inside tag ScrollView. If I remove it, works. I have tried remove padding and margin of ScrollView and nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The inner StackLayout is required for the ScrollView to work properly. If I have more than one element (such as an input form - which is the scenario in my application), only the last element is displayed without the StackLayout.